# Wifi Connection problems on UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, connection

I installed UBUNTU 18.04 in a partition with Windows 10 on my Asus and although it connects during 1 minute when the system is started, it disconnects and keeps trying to connect without being able to.

My Problem: I can see your wireless access point, but cannot establish a connection.

```
andrea@andrea-N750JK:~$ ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.130.1.229  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.130.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fca9:8485:2dbe:234b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:2c:4a:3f:51:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 383  bytes 500523 (500.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 324  bytes 33089 (33.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 130  bytes 10218 (10.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 130  bytes 10218 (10.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:35:30:98:47:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have checked every single post on this page and haven't been able to fix it. Any ideas??

Thank you in advance for your time!

EDIT1:

I have added all the info from the package downloaded using

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info`
HERE IS THE FILE INFO-->

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kwXZQ8pxQj/

Comment: Start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @mikewhatever Hello! thanks for the comment. I have edited the post and have added the information downloaded that the post required.